# How to list files that have been created/removed between given commits

Tags: git

Is there an easy way to list files that have been added and/or removed from given branch between some arbitrary commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

```
git log 0be3204 61bd4f0 --diff-filter=AD --summary --oneline
```

### Output

```
0be3204 Delete two files.
 delete mode 100644 test2.txt
 delete mode 100644 test3.txt
f7f92cc Add a new file
 create mode 100644 test3.txt
3bcb423 Delete one file.
 delete mode 100644 test.txt
61bd4f0 Create two files.
 create mode 100644 test.txt
 create mode 100644 test2.txt
```

### Explanation

- `git log` lists your commits.
- `0be3204 61bd4f0` indicates the start and end commit range.
- `--diff-filter=AD` means to show only files that were added/deleted. Use the `D` character alone to list only deleted files.
- `--summary` describes newly added, deleted, renamed and copied files.
- `--oneline` (optional) includes the SHA1 and the commit message in the result.

Answer (score -1):

```
git diff --stat commit1..commit2
```

Comment: How do we interpret the output?